# What type of media contains the installation image

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization, qemu, rhev

I have installed RHEV in one HP G9 blade. Now I want to create a guest VM with Linux. In order to proceed I have copied the image to RHEV machine and mounted that iso in /mnt/iso. I am using below command to install:

```
virt-install --accelerate --hvm --connect qemu:///system \
--network=bridge:control,model=virtio --ram=4096 --vcpus=2 --os-type=linux \
--os-variant=rhel5.4 --nographics --location=/mnt/iso --name=TestVM2 \
--extra-args='console=ttyS0' --disk none
```

`--location=/mnt/iso` is my mount point and the iso image is in `/root` .

I am getting blocked in below screen . Could anyone suggest how to proceed??

What type of media contains the installation image?
Local CD/DVD
Hard Drive
NFS Directory
URL

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you provided a directory to the `--location` option. When you do this, virt-install can only boot with the kernel/initrd in that directory, but the contents of the directory are not provided to the virtual machine.

The man page also warns about this:

```
           DIRECTORY
               Path to a local directory containing an installable
               distribution image. Note that the directory will not be
               accessible by the guest after initial boot, so the OS installer
               will need another way to access the rest of the install media.
```

Using a directory for `--location` has this limitation, but other possible parameters do not.

If you intended to provide boot media to the virtual machine, you should instead provide the location of the ISO image. You do not need to mount the image. For example:

```
--location /var/lib/libvirt/isos/CentOS-6.10-x86_64-DVD.iso
```

Comment: I tried it and got the below error. 
ERROR    internal error: qemu unexpectedly closed the monitor: 2019-06-22 03:05:58.409+0000: Domain id=20 is tainted: high-privileges
qemu: could not load kernel '/var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinst-vmlinuz.PKfATH': No such file or directory
Domain installation does not appear to have been successful.
If it was, you can restart your domain by running:

Comment: Eh? Does that directory exist? It should have been created when libvirtd was installed.

Comment: [root@p8-server-11 ~]# ll /var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinst-vmlinuz.guIGNo
ls: cannot access /var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinst-vmlinuz.guIGNo: No such file or directory
[root@p8-server-11 ~]# ll /var/lib/libvirt/boot/
total 0